# How to solve chrome extension Icon not working problem

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I created a todo Extension and when I tried to give it an icon It said this

"**Failed to load extension File**:
~\Desktop\Youtube Design\ToDo Mobile App\Extension

**Error**:
Could not load icon 'icon16.png' specified in 'icons'.Could not load manifest."

*manifest code:*

```
{
    "name": "ToDo Extension",
    "description": "saves todos",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Joyal George K J",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "32": "icon32.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
      },
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "icon32.png",
        "default_title": "ToDo List Extension"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"]
}
```

What is the problem? I did exactly what is said in the documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/icons)

Comment: The error means there's no such file (it's in the wrong location or its name is different e.g. Icon16.png) or it's in an incompatible format so maybe you'll need to use a different icon editor/converter.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yap, Thanks Brother I forgot that it was inside the images folder! My bad.